# Criar método separado para chamar activity

Tags: android-studio, classes, android-activity, método

eu criei um script onde eu pretendo chamar activities separadas

mas nao esta funcionando

```
package com.example.john.new_login;
```

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.example.john.new_login.login.Cadastro;
import com.example.john.new_login.login.RecuperaSenha;

/**
 * Created by John on 09/12/2017.
 */

public class Botoes_Login {

```
private static Context context;

public static void Registro() {
    Intent registro = new Intent(context, Cadastro.class);
    context.startActivity(registro);
}

public static void RecuperaSenha() {
    Intent recuperasenha = new Intent(context, RecuperaSenha.class);
    context.startActivity(recuperasenha);
}

public static void Login() {
    Intent login = new Intent(context, Login.class);
    context.startActivity(login);
}
```

}

como seria a maneira correta de criar uma classe para isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixa eu ver se entendi.

Você criou uma classe ChamarActivities com alguns metodos. Ai você pretende dar, por exemplo, ChamarActivities.Login() pra o método já fazer a transição de Activities? Se sim, creio que seu script já funciona, você só deve, antes de chamar o método, preencher o atributo context com o contexto da tela atual. Mas te recomendo tirar este atributo estático e passar o contexto por parametro.

Ex:

```
ChamarActivities.Login(MainActivity.this);
```

Se o que eu falei não adianta, creio que esteja dando algum outro erro, qual seria?

Comment: era exatamente isso, eu estava esquecendo de passar o Context para as classes, desta maneira, n iria dar certo mesmo, obrigado